# HDR Help - Photoshop Cs5

Tags: hdr, olympus, bracketing, moon, photoshop-cs5

I have made, with auto-bracketing, a set of 3 pictures of the moon to merge it with the HDR auto-merge function of Photoshop. The problem is that PS Cs5 is not being able to compensate the movement of the moon. Wat can I do to compensate this and merge it to do a HDR picture?

Comment: Why would you use hdr for he moon? That's not a very contrasty subject.

Comment: @ths Well, that all depends upon how one looks at it. The full moon is not very contrasty. When the moon is partially illuminated by the sun it is VERY contrasty, but we usually don't worry about the part that is in shadow. But the brightness difference there is so great that even HDR can't usually deal with the difference. Multiple exposures 12 or 14 stops apart would need to be composited, rather than merged using HDR methods.

Comment: Related: [How can I capture earthshine?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42458/15871)

Comment: Related: [How do I capture the moon and its surrounding context?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/52043/15871)

Comment: As the photographic results from the question and the answers from the second question linked above show, HDR probably isn't the way to go when shooting the moon.

Comment: As the images in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/41724/15871) illustrate, getting a photo of the detail of the part of the moon's surface in shadow is nigh impossible unless the moon is nearly new AND the shooting location is under relatively dry air (or no air at all).

Comment: @MichaelClark,
 this is the picture I´ve made from the moon (one of them),
 which I still would like to use to do a HDR. I still would like to try the HDR, even if it is not the best way to do it.
 (https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM9Q7LMo0Aw4nXaFjXe8wo97wiaHmgYCsQAXQDNS1RWqF4FVS1ti0Zl-wz_abM_-w?key=Mlgwd094NmNRZGhsUTh6Y3dCZTdTNUdkcGhOY2l3)

Comment: @PedroRöhl What do you hope to accomplish by using HDR on that photo? What do you want it to look like when you are done?

Comment: @MichaelClark I would like to try to have a picture with enhanced definition of the moon.

Comment: You're going to have to start with image(s) with more definition. There are many questions here regarding how to do that with the moon.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the free software [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) to achieve this. Although primarily for building panorama's Hugin is a GUI for various tools including align_image_stack for aligning stacks of images in preparation for creating [focus stacks](https://patdavid.net/2013/01/focus-stacking-macro-photos-enfuse.html) or [HDR](https://sites.google.com/site/alistargazing/home/image-processing/hugin-tutorial-enfuse-only) blends with [enfuse](http://enblend.sourceforge.net/index.htm). With a little experimentation you can use the tools either from the command line or from within Hugin.
 You can take the output at any time and use it in Photoshop or follow the process through with Hugin's panotools.

See also [panotools wiki](http://wiki.panotools.org/Align_a_stack_of_photos).